# How to get the value from Javascript Prompt Box and Pass it into PHP variable to be able to save in SQL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Here is my problem, I want my script to do this:
-before the user reject entry(server side), system must prompt text box asking the reason why they want to reject it. and then save the reason they input to MySQL server.

Javascript Function:

```
function MyReason(){
    var reason = prompt("Reason");
}
```

PHP Snippet:

```
echo "<td> <a href=changeStatReject.php?id=" . $row['id'] . ">"  . "<img src='media/reject.png'>" . "</a></td>";
```

From Here, I want to get the value of prompt box and pass it to

> changeStatReject.php

and save it in DB.

Thanks Mates.

Comment: There're 2 options. Use ajax or submit form.

Comment: how can I use submit in this @manassorn

Comment: I'd recommend you go for the jQuery-library to make Ajax easier. Take a look at this really simple and basic tutorial: [Link]http://www.ajaxtutorial.net/index.php/2010/03/03/basic-ajax-usage-with-jquery/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send value to hidden input in the form and submit it.

```
function MyReason(){
    var reason = prompt("Reason");
    document.getElementById("reason").value = reason;
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
}

<form id="form">
    <input type="hidden" id="reason" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very BIG @manassorn. It already solved my problem. God Bless You!

Comment: 1 more thing, I'm trying to catch error if user don't input anything

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
function MyReason(){
    var reason =  prompt("Reason");
    document.getElementById('hiddenNameField').value = reason;
    document.forms(0).submit();
}
```

Comment: about hiddenNameField, i will add it in the changeStatReject.php?

Comment: yse, you should to add it in your html(php) file